# VB.NET ping on port

Tags: vb.net, networking, ip, port, ping

Im trying to make a server status checker that can ping on a port.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.2.10:21") Then
        PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Label1.Text = "Online!"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen

    Else
        PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.DarkRed
        Label1.Text = "Offline!"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
    End If
End Sub
```

When i do this, it doesnt return any results. No offline or online.

Comment: @qwr Yes. Like i said it returned no data.

Comment: @user3059238, `Network.Ping` must return a value, either `True` or `False`

Comment: Also note that ping address should be without port.

Comment: @bk320 check answer. hope it be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted on comment ping with port will not work.So with it you can check only remote availability. And writing with `"ipaddress:port"` should throw error

> Ping operates by sending Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)

Other ways to do so is to use TCP

Here I wrote proper ways for Pinging port and Neetwork.Ping

```
Private Function checkport(hostname As String, port As Integer
                             ) As Boolean
    Dim client As New TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork)


    client.BeginConnect(hostname, port,
                        Sub(x)
                            Dim tcp As TcpClient = CType(x.AsyncState, TcpClient)
                            Try
                                tcp.EndConnect(x)
                                SetIndicators(True)

                            Catch ex As Exception
                                'error
                                SetIndicators(False)

                            End Try
                            tcp.Close()
                        End Sub, client
                        )


    Return (False)
End Function

'Cross-thread safe code using InvokeRequired Pattern
Private Sub SetIndicators(ByVal ok As Boolean)

    If Me.Label1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New Action(Of Boolean)(AddressOf SetIndicators)
        Me.Invoke(d, ok)
    Else
        If ok = True Then
            Label1.Text = "Online!"
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Offline!"
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
       ' If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.1.1") Then

          '  Label1.Text = "Online!"
          '  Label1.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen

       ' Else
           ' Label1.Text = "Offline!"
           ' Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
       ' End If 
        SetIndicators(My.Computer.Network.Ping("stackoverflow.com")) 
    Catch ex As Exception
        'error occured
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'result can be returned late according connection timeout
    checkport("stackoverflow.com", 450) 
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'should return online cause http port accessible
    checkport("stackoverflow.com", 80)
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't this just check if a Port is open on the router? Not sure this answers the OP's post. Have tried it testing port 21 when server on my LAN is running and not running - returns "online!" when server is both on and off - presumably because Port 21 is open + forwarded on my router?

Comment: Firstly, Check correctness of your remote local ip address if you are using DHCP. Secondly, check router. Doesn't this just check if a Port is open on the router? In any case it will only  return online when it connects to server that listens on 21 (ftp). On most routers there is just one port listened (80) which we use to  configure router itself.